# excluding rows from resultset in postgres

Tags: postgresql, join, left-join

This is my result set

[image: resultset]

i am returning this result set on the base of `refid` using `WHERE refid IN`.
Over here, i need to apply a logic without any kind of programming (means SQL query only).

if in result set, i am getting `period` for particular `refid` then other rows with the same `refid` must not returned.

for example, 2667105 having `period` then `myid` = 612084598 must not get returned in result set.

according to me this can be achieved using CASE but i have no idea how to use it, i mean that i don't know should i use the `CASE` statement in `SELECT` statement or `WHERE` clause...

---

EDIT:

This is how it suppose to work,

`myid` = 612084598 is the default row for `refid` = 2667105 but if specifically wants the `refid` for `period` = 6 then it must return all rows except `myid` = 612084598

but if i am looking for `period` = 12, for this `period` no specific `refid` present in database.. so for this it must return all rows except first one.. means all rows with the `refid` which is default one..

Answer (score 2):

Not very clear definition of the problem, but try this:

```
with cte as (
    select
        *,
        first_value(period) over(partition by refid order by myid) as fv
    from test
)
select
    myid, refid, period
from cte
where period is not null or fv is null
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/c0164/2)

Comment: @KuKu still not very clear, please provide default input for your test cases